# Display what taxonomies a custom post has?

Tags: custom-post-types, terms

I've trying to search high and low for this but am having a really hard time.

Essentially, I have a custom post type called `locations` with taxonomies. The posts in "locations" are categorized under several taxonomies called `markets`, `products`, `size`, `country`, etc."

I just need to know how I can get it so my custom post type on the front end displays what taxonomies the post is categorized into. Does anyone know how I can do that?

To clarify, I just basically need to emulate this page to a tee (which is a drupal site) where you can see what categories the post if under.

> http://www.playtime.com/Acadiana-Mall-Lafayette-LA

Would greatly appreciate ANY guidance or feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there's multiple Taxonomies, you will need to loop through all of the assigned taxonomies of that post type. `get_object_taxonomies` is the function which returns array of post type taxonomies.

```
global $post;
foreach ( get_object_taxonomies( $post ) as $tax_name ){
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $tax_name );
    $label = $taxonomy->labels->name;

    the_terms( $post->ID, $tax_name, $label . ': ', ', ' );
}
```

Comment: AWESOME!  That helped so much and got what I needed. You're a rockstar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for [`the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms)